# How do I properly constrain these UIImageViews in Xcode's IB?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uiimageview, constraints

I have a freeform sized UIView on my IB, with dimension's of 600x600, within it I have six UIImageView's all sized 300x200 making them all fit evenly within the view. The issue is I'm having a hard time finding the correct constraints to make them appear evenly sized and positioned in my app as it is in my IB. Here is the IB to Preview comparison:

[image]

What constraints should I add to each UIImageView to make them appear in my app as they do in the IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

Use the *multiplier* to configure the width and height of these views. Each view has a width of 1/2 the width of its superview, and a height 1/3 the height of its superview. Pin the edges appropriately and you're all set.

Another way:

Use *stack views*. Use two vertical stack views inside a horizontal stack view. Set the distribution of all three stack views to UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually. Pin all four sides of the outer stack view to the superview. (The stack views are merely doing for you what I advised in the previous approach.)

In these screen shots, I did it with the stack views. Notice that we are perfectly arranged on both a 6s and 4s:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I prefer your 1st approach, so before I use the multiplier to effect the ratio of the width and height, I should set the width and height constraints equal to the superview first correct?

Comment: You cannot use the multiplier to do "the ratio of the width and height". You are setting the width and height in relation to the superview, not one another. That's basic arithmetic!

Comment: Cool! If you did it with the first approach, you are (1) a total expert and (2) compatible back to iOS 8 and before where there are no stack views. I did it with stack views just because it was so easy and fast. :)